# spring-batch Read a file that contains file names to be ingested

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have the following case and I am trying to solve it with **Spring-Boot** and **Spring-Batch**. I have to read a flat file (sidecar file) in which every line is a name of a file to be ingested in a database.

I have configured a job to read the sidecar file, but I am having a problem to decide what is the accepted method in **spring-batch** to process the contained files. I also have configured steps that can read each file and insert the records in a data base.

Any ideas how to configure the sidecar job with the steps I have written for the individual files.

I can provide actual configuration from my implementation if needed.

Comment: I found useful information in this two articles [Spring Batch lists of lists and how to read them](http://www.desynit.com/dev-zone/java/spring-batch-lists-of-lists-and-how-to-read-them/) and [Spring Batch – How to read lists of lists](http://www.desynit.com/dev-zone/java/spring-batch-read-lists-lists-part-ii/)

Answer (score 0):

`FactoryBean` is your friend.  In this case, you can create a `FactoryBean` that reads the file of file names and creates a list of `Resource` objects for it.  That can be injected into the `MultiResourceItemReader` which will iterate over that list.